# WAMP server cannot find the local host via chrome

Tags: wamp

I installed WAMP but got a error message: This localhost page can’t be found.  I tried everything suggested by this website and still can't solve the problem.  Here are extracted from my conf file:
ServerName localhost:8080/

## Listen 12.34.56.78:8080

Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
Listen [::0]:8080

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change the permission of your htdocs folder?

Or did you  try to stand up your wamp server
After the installation you have to wake up your server

Comment: I simply follow the instruction to install.  I only change the port to 8080.  I don't think I change the permission nor try to stand up my wamp server.  How can I do that?

Comment: I finally got it after watching a tons of youtube videos.  I have to type in localhost:8080 in Chrome.  F.I.N.A.L.L.Y.!!!!